# reading and extract data from a complex text file

Tags: python, formatting, text-files

I am a beginner with python and I try to use it to automate repetitive tasks. I'm struggling a lot with the following task:
I have a bunch of text files formatted in the following way:

```
Cluster (x,y,z)         size   size p-FWE   size p-FDR   size p-unc         mass   mass p-FWE   mass p-FDR   mass p-unc
-44 -58 +36              361     0.049000     0.030607     0.000068      3797.10     0.058000     0.036292     0.000081
-38 -84 +18              344     0.057000     0.030607     0.000079      3386.52     0.071000     0.036292     0.000107
-42 -06 +30              259     0.108000     0.045083     0.000175      3072.19     0.091000     0.036292     0.000141




Cluster -44 -58 +36  :
248 voxels (69%) covering 5% of atlas.sLOC l (Lateral Occipital Cortex, superior division Left)
51 voxels (14%) covering 5% of atlas.AG l (Angular Gyrus Left)
62 voxels (17%) covering 0% of atlas.not-labeled

Cluster -38 -84 +18  :
163 voxels (47%) covering 3% of atlas.sLOC l (Lateral Occipital Cortex, superior division Left)
107 voxels (31%) covering 5% of atlas.iLOC l (Lateral Occipital Cortex, inferior division Left)
25 voxels (7%) covering 1% of atlas.OP l (Occipital Pole Left)
49 voxels (14%) covering 0% of atlas.not-labeled

Cluster -42 -6 +30  :
89 voxels (34%) covering 2% of atlas.PreCG l (Precentral Gyrus Left)
1 voxels (0%) covering 0% of atlas.IFG oper l (Inferior Frontal Gyrus, pars opercularis Left)
169 voxels (65%) covering 0% of atlas.not-labeled

All clusters combined :
411 voxels (43%) covering 8% of atlas.sLOC l (Lateral Occipital Cortex, superior division Left)
107 voxels (11%) covering 5% of atlas.iLOC l (Lateral Occipital Cortex, inferior division Left)
89 voxels (9%) covering 2% of atlas.PreCG l (Precentral Gyrus Left)
51 voxels (5%) covering 5% of atlas.AG l (Angular Gyrus Left)
25 voxels (3%) covering 1% of atlas.OP l (Occipital Pole Left)
1 voxels (0%) covering 0% of atlas.IFG oper l (Inferior Frontal Gyrus, pars opercularis Left)
280 voxels (29%) covering 0% of atlas.not-labeled
```

I would like to read and format into a dataframe in the way described in the table below.

It is unfortunately well beyond my beginner's competencies and I am therefore seeking for some help to build a python script.
Thank you very much for your appreciated

| Seed_ROI | Cluster (x,y,z) | size | size p-FWE | size p-FDR | size p-unc | mass | mass p-FWE | mass p-FDR | mass p-unc | voxels | covering | region |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| FP_I | -44 -58 +36 | 361 | 0.049000 | 0.030607 | 0.000068 | 3797.10 | 0.058000 | 0.036292 | 0.000081 | 248 | 5 | atlas.sLOC (Lateral Occipital Cortex, superior division left) |
| FP_I | -44 -58 +36 | 361 | 0.049000 | 0.030607 | 0.000068 | 3797.10 | 0.058000 | 0.036292 | 0.000081 | 51 | 5 | atlas.AG l (Angular Gyrus Left) |
| FP_I | -44 -58 +36 | 361 | 0.049000 | 0.030607 | 0.000068 | 3797.10 | 0.058000 | 0.036292 | 0.000081 | 62 | 0 | atlas.not-labeled |
| FP_I | -38 -84 +18 | 344 | 0.057000 | 0.030607 | 0.000079 | 3386.52 | 0.071000 | 0.036292 | 0.000107 | 163 | 3 | atlas.sLOC (lateral Occipital Cortex, superior division Left) |

The first column contains the name of the directory where the file is located. I obtain it using the following command line

```
import glob
import os

path = "C:/MRIdata/CONN_analysis/conn_Ent02/results/secondlevel/SBC_01/Entrepreneurs(1).Managers(-1)/rest/*/"
subdirs2 = glob.glob('%s'%(path))

for dir in subdirs2:
    seedRegion = os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(dir))
    new_file = os.path.join(dir, "results.Table.txt")
```

Comment: Your table is too hard to perceive. Can you edit it in a readable fashion?

Comment: I have made the changes. Is it better looking? On my computer the table is correctly displayed

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way you can do this. I copied your sample text file content and saved in a file. There might be more efficient ways to do it. But this should work.

You should be getting a list-dict like this:

```
[{'Cluster (x,y,z)': '-44 -58 +3', 'size': ' 361', 'size p-FWE': '0.049000', 'size p-FDR': '0.030607', 'size p-unc': '0.000068', 'mass': ' 3797.10', 'mass p-FWE': 
'0.058000', 'mass p-FDR': '0.036292', 'mass p-unc': '0.000081'}, {'Cluster (x,y,z)': '-38 -84 +1', 'size': ' 344', 'size p-FWE': '0.057000', 'size p-FDR': '0.030607', 'size p-unc': '0.000079', 'mass': ' 3386.52', 'mass p-FWE': '0.071000', 'mass p-FDR': '0.036292', 'mass p-unc': '0.000107'}, {'Cluster (x,y,z)': '-42 -06 +3', 
'size': ' 259', 'size p-FWE': '0.108000', 'size p-FDR': '0.045083', 'size p-unc': '0.000175', 'mass': ' 3072.19', 'mass p-FWE': '0.091000', 'mass p-FDR': '0.036292', 'mass p-unc': '0.000141'}]
```

Here is the updated code

```
headers=['Cluster (x,y,z)','size','size p-FWE','size p-FDR','size p-unc','mass','mass p-FWE','mass p-FDR','mass p-unc']
data=[]
with open("katerlo.txt","r") as txtfile:
    data=txtfile.readlines()


final_data=[]
for i in range(len(data)):
    if(i==0):
        continue #we skip the first line
    header_index=0 
    line=data[i]
    #i am using a crude way to do it, since I can see that your data is in a fixed range
    #also, I will output a json/list-dict instead of a table, I believe you can take it from there
    
    if(len(line)<=2): #i am assuming your main interest is the first part, so I am not going to parse the bottom part
        print(len(line))
        break

    first_col_data=line[:10] #extracting the odd first column

    cur_json={}
    cur_json[headers[header_index]]=first_col_data
    header_index=header_index+1
    line=line[24:] #i am skipping the large spacing which looks like completely defined
    remaining_col_arr=line.split("     ") #the spacing defined in your text file as the delimiter
    for item in remaining_col_arr:
        item=item.replace('\n','') #replace endline character if it appears. There are much more efficient ways to do this though
        cur_json[headers[header_index]]=item #extracting the remaining column data
        header_index=header_index+1
    final_data.append(cur_json)
print(final_data)
```

Comment: Thank you very veryv much for this script. When I run it I have an error message replace expected at least 2 arguments, got 1 the error is coming from this line item=item.replace('\n') #replace endline character if it appears. There are much more efficient ways to do this though

Comment: My bad, it should be item=item.replace('\n','')